# ¿Cómo obtener el código fuente de una función en R? (paquete "car")

Tags: r, funciones, algoritmos

El paquete "car" en R tiene una interesante función que se llama outlierTest y quiero analizar su código fuente para entender su funcionamiento. Intenté lo siguiente y obtuve un error:

```
getMethod("outlierTest")

    Error in getMethod("outlierTest") : 
     no generic function found for 'outlierTest'
```

Con esto parece que obtengo una respuesta pero me redirecciona a una página en la que no se muestran códigos fuente:

```
methods(outlierTest)
    [1] outlierTest.lm*
    see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Finalmente, al tipear solo "outlierTest" en consola no obtengo respuesta:

```
outlierTest
    function (model, ...) 
    {
          UseMethod("outlierTest")
    }
<bytecode: 0x000000000cf4d3d0>
<environment: namespace:car>
```

Agradezco cualquier orientación al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente, al menos con este paquete funciona:

Buscamos los métodos:

```
> methods("outlierTest")
[1] outlierTest.lm*
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

Particularmente el método `outlierTest.lm` que tiene un `*` según la documentación:

> The S3 method name is followed by an asterisk * if the method
>   definition is not exported from the package namespace in which the
>   method is defined

Para recuperar en este caso su código podemos intentar esto:

```
getAnywhere('outlierTest.lm')
```

Sino la alternativa es acceder directamente al github del proyecto y puntualmente esta función la recuperas en [este enlace](https://github.com/cran/car/blob/master/R/outlierTest.R)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! La liga a github es particularmente útil. Saludos.

Comment: No conocía el  `getAnywhere` +1!

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa es que puedes acceder a funciones "no exportadas" (no visibles en tu namespace) con tripe ":"

Recuerda que como ves, la funcion `outlierTest` es genérica y para acceder que en particular se aplica a objetos de la clase `lm` debes agregar un punto: `functiongenerica.clase`:

```
car:::outlierTest.lm


function (model, cutoff = 0.05, n.max = 10, order = TRUE, labels = names(rstudent), 
    ...) 
{
    rstudent <- rstudent(model)
    if (length(rstudent) != length(labels)) 
        stop("Number of labels does not correspond to number of residuals.")
    else names(rstudent) <- labels
    df <- df.residual(model) - 1
    rstudent <- rstudent[!is.na(rstudent)]
    n <- length(rstudent)
    p <- if (class(model)[1] == "glm") 
        2 * (pnorm(abs(rstudent), lower.tail = FALSE))
    else 2 * (pt(abs(rstudent), df, lower.tail = FALSE))
    bp <- n * p
    ord <- if (order) 
        order(bp)
    else 1:n
    ord <- ord[bp[ord] <= cutoff]
    result <- if (length(ord) == 0) {
        which <- which.max(abs(rstudent))
        list(rstudent = rstudent[which], p = p[which], bonf.p = bp[which], 
            signif = FALSE, cutoff = cutoff)
    }
    else {
        if (length(ord) > n.max) 
            ord <- ord[1:n.max]
        result <- list(rstudent = rstudent[ord], p = p[ord], 
            bonf.p = bp[ord], signif = TRUE, cutoff = cutoff)
    }
    class(result) <- "outlierTest"
    result
}
<bytecode: 0x000000001e2258a0>
<environment: namespace:car>
```

Comment: Había olvidado agradecer tu orientación. Saludos y feliz inicio de año.